# Don't show corresponding field items

Tags: ms-access

I want to run a query that will end up showing only items that don't have a corresponding value.

So for example: Say table1 had 5 items and table2 had the same 5 items, but had an additional 2 more items. How would I make the query only show the 2 additional items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a `LEFT JOIN` between the tables to return the rows that are not in both tables:

```
select table2.id
from table2 
left join table1
    on table2.id = table1.id
where table1.id is null
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great reference:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

See a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac1ff/1) (Note: the demo is sql server but the syntax would be the same)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table2.id
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE (((table1.id) Is Null));
```